# Ionic push notification api in c# with WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send a push notification using the ionic push notifications api, using c# with WebApi.
The python example from ionic website is working perfectly, but I can't get it working in c#, although it seems that the requests are the same.
This is my code:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Ionic-Application-Id", IONIC_APP_ID);
                //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var keyBase64 = "Basic " + IONIC_PRIVATE_KEY_BASE_64;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", keyBase64);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
                //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");


                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("push", json).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    int a = 6;
                }
            }
```

I keep getting bad request (400), with no further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, solved it!
The problem was with the Content-Type header, the "PostAsJsonAsync" method default content-type is "application/json; charset=utf-8", while the api is expecting "application/json".

This works:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(API_URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Ionic-Application-Id", IONIC_APP_ID);
            var keyBase64 = "Basic " + IONIC_PRIVATE_KEY_BASE_64;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", keyBase64);
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, api);
            request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;                
        }
```

For clarity, the calling function is :

```
public void Send(string regId, string msg, int notificationId)
    {
        dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
        data.tokens = new List<string>() {regId};
        data.notification = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic;
        data.notification.alert = msg;

        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        log.InfoFormat("Sending notifcation to {0}, message is {1} ", regId, msg);
        SendToIonic("push", json);           

    }
```

Comment: Where is 'api' variable coming from in the HttpRequestMessage set? Is that your API_URL as well?

Comment: And what does your json look like?

Comment: In this case 'API' is 'push', see my answer edit for the json

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("A_Test")]
    public HttpResponseMessage A_Test()
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        try
        {

            string regId = "";
            string profile = "<Name of Security Profile>";
            string msg = "Test";

            string data = "{ \"tokens\":[],\"send_to_all\":" + "true" + ",\"profile\":\"" + profile + "\",\"notification\":{\"message\":\"" + msg + "\"}}";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Ionic-Application-Id", "<Ionic App ID>");

                var keyBase64 = "Bearer " + "<Security Token>";
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", keyBase64);

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications");
                request.Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

            }

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            response.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(string), ex.Message, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json");

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used RestClient:

```
public async Task Send(string userId, string devicePushToken, string content)
{

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        tokens = new[] {devicePushToken},
        profile = "yourprofile",
        notification = new
        {
            message = content
        }
    });

    var restClient = new RestClient("https://api.ionic.io/");
    var restRequest = new RestRequest("push/notifications", Method.POST);
    restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    restRequest.AddParameter("Authorization",
        "Bearer APIKEY",
        ParameterType.HttpHeader);

    await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(restRequest);
}
```