# Ionic push notification api in c#

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, ionic-framework

So based on Tom Raz post [Ionic push notification api in c# with WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653934/ionic-push-notification-api-in-c-sharp-with-webapi). I tried to implement a method to send a push notification using the ionic push notifications api here is my code:

```
    public void sendToIonic(string regId, string msg) {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string data = "{ \"user_ids\":[\" "+ regId + "\"],\"notification\":{\"alert\":\" "+ msg + "\"}}";

            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Ionic-Application-Id", "1d74b1f2");
            var keyBase64 = "Basic %s" + "53a03dc7d9ce58511263e40580294f62af36b89be7cc4db2";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", keyBase64);
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push");

            request.Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
        }

    }
```

But I keep getting the response `error 403 Forbidden;`. This is the complete response:

> {StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     Connection: keep-alive
>     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>     Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
>     Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 20:50:33 GMT
>     ETag: W/"35-nGlZv/eC8CyS+KJzQ1P9rg"
>     Server: Cowboy
>     Via: 1.1 vegur
>     X-Powered-By: Express
>     Content-Length: 53
>     Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   }}

Not sure what is wrong. I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var keyBase64 = "Basic %s" + "..."
```

> %s this is to concatenate in python.
>   You need to convert to Base64

You can use

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Ionic-Application-Id", "1d74b1f2");
var IONIC_PRIVATE_KEY_BASE_64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("53a03dc7d9ce58511263e40580294f62af36b89be7cc4db2:")); // ends with two points
var keyBase64 = "Basic " + IONIC_PRIVATE_KEY_BASE_64 ;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", keyBase64);
```

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push#section-authenticating-your-requests